# How to telnet to a unix socket in debian to test memcached

Tags: memcached, telnet, unix-sockets

To test memcached on Ubuntu, I would run this command:

```
echo "stats settings" | nc -U /run/mydir/memcached.sock
```

However now I have changed to Debian, and Debian `nc` does not support the `-U` option.

I have tried `ss`, `listen`, `telnet -b /run/mydir/memcached.sock` with no joy.

What is the equivalent command in Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `ncat` or the `netcat-openbsd` package, both provides a version of `nc` supporting `-U`.

If you don't have `nc`, you can connect to a unix socket with `socat` like this:

```
socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/the/path/to/the/socket
```

Comment: netcat-openbsd did the trick thanks!